# Use Adb programmatically

Tags: android, adb, root

How can I Push my apk from the Data Folder to the System/App Folder using a Rooted Device, programmatically using `Runtime.getRuntime().exe`.

Should I use Pull, Push or Cat Command and how?

Does it will affect Shared Prefs or anything?

Comment: None of the above - adb is for use from a connected development machine, not from the device itself.  What you are trying to do should be strongly discouraged, but would probably be implemented either with your own copying code, or using a shell to launch an instance of cat with the output redirected.  But please don't pursue this project - it needs to be reviewed in detail for security and stability by someone with the wisdom of Android and unix expertise your question indicates you do not have.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer , i just know that System app , i mean apk in System Folder are 100% Protected this is enought for me as my app is Not a virus or Not Malicious , also , many app in Google Play have this Feature

Comment: You are severely mistaken - system apps are NOT protected from attack, other than to a small degree in the trivial and rarely exploited manner of overwriting their code.  Instead, they tend to become easily opened doors for attacking the device. Novice attempts at writing them will almost certainly introduce severe security holes placing everything on the device at risk - if the ham handed attempt at installing them doesn't break it first.

Comment: Yes , thats true , i care on this ...

Comment: This is a real and quite specific question, so as far as SO is concerned it should not be closed.  However, it isn't something the poster should be trying to do without orders of magnitude more expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install -r "/path/to/yourfilename.apk";)
```

Usage 
pm install [-l] [-r] [-t] [-i INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME] [-s] [-f]
                  [--algo  --key  --iv ] PATH

options :

```
-l: install the package with FORWARD_LOCK.
-r: reinstall an exisiting app, keeping its data.
-t: allow test .apks to be installed.
-i: specify the installer package name.
-s: install package on sdcard.
-f: install package on internal flash.
```

Depending on your usage of the -r parameter, it will affect the shared preferences xml files (use to not lose).

Comment: That would only install as a regular app, unless the certificates match (in which case the poster wouldn't be asking here).  It also won't compile given the typos.

Comment: Thanks , but should i need the source path >> Destination Path ?

Comment: @Chris , please Explain Why it is so Dangerous , my App , it like putting a Blank file in the System Folder , its not a Security breach ...

Comment: the source path is wherever your apk file is bundled in or downloaded to.

Comment: @forgive my apk is in /data/app currently , so the pm install command will push 'itself'(my apk) to the destination path , so no need source path , as there is no source path as parameter

Comment: or should i do "pm install -r "/data/app/MyAPK.apk"

Comment: okay Thanks you , so If No Parameter , it will Install to the System Folder ...

Comment: Okay i have tested but Nothing happen , No LogCat , also , i tried to exec "su" with sucess

Comment: `pm install -r "/data/app/MyAPK.apk` should be good.  Your app may also need permissions.  Check the logcat diligently.

Comment: Yes , but about the quote just " & " at the end ? All Permission are set

Comment: with adb on my pc i get a success operation but the apk is not pushed to the system folder

Comment: This answer cannot work as is, and would not solve your problem anyway, so why did you accept it?

Comment: LOOOOL i was Banned !!!!!!!!! Why ? and in Stack i know the Only Way to Get UnBanned is to Read the "Why do i get Banned and How to Get Unbanned ?" Topic But the "Why do i get Banned and How to Get Unbanned ?" Topic SAY TO Read the "Why do i get Banned and How to Get Unbanned ?" To Get Unbanned LOOOOL

Answer (score -1):

Well you need to pull the actual apk, not the applications folder inside `/data`

But after you get the APK, you can use the command:
`adb push myapp.apk /system/app`
To push it to the `/system/app` folder. When you push an apk to `/data/app`, it installs it as a system app
Don't do `adb install myapp.apk` or it will install as a normal app
To achieve this, pair the commands above with `Runtime.exec()` or look up how to use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class

Comment: Thanks you , but i mean Programmaticly

Comment: Exactly, you can pair this with `Runtime.exec()` to get it done.

Comment: so the command should be "su , -c , adb? push /data/app/xxxx.apk /system/app/xxxxx.apk

Comment: Wait, I misunderstood. Will you be running this command from the device itself or from a computer?

Comment: from the Device itself !

Comment: Ok then the command would be the following (you need busybox installed)

`su -c 'cp /data/app/xxx /system/app/xxx'`

Comment: Thanks , but Nothing Happen ...

Comment: Using this :    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su" , "-c" , "cp /data/app/com.MyApp.apk /system/app/MyApp.apk"}); it ask me for root ...

Comment: now , i have pushed it with adb for testing , but i get a Force Close when i run my app with a NullPointerExeption on setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: this is ok now i tested with adb , but its Useless beacause in Jelly Bean 4.2 we can Disable System App